# Select n items by sequence of a list repeatedly in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, iterator

Say I have a long list:

```
>>> import string
>>> my_list = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
>>> my_list
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

I want to loop over this list and select n items by sequence repeatedly. E.g. if I want to select 5 items, then it should be like:

```
step 1: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
step 2: ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
step 3: ['k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o']
step 4: ['p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't']
step 5: ['u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y']
step 6: ['z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
step 7: ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
......
```

So the point is: **I want to make sure when I reach the last item of the list, the first items can be appended to the last one and the looping just keep going.**

---

For appending the first items to the last items, I've tried something like this:

```
def loop_slicing(lst_, i):
    """ Slice iterable repeatedly """
    if i[0] > i[1]:
        return [n for n in lst_[i[0]:]+lst_[:i[1]]]
    else:
        return lst_[i[0]:i[1]]
```

When I call this function, I can do this:

```
>>> loop_slicing(my_list, (0, 5))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> loop_slicing(my_list, (25, 4))
['z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Where I can just make a generator which can generate 5 sequential numbers in `range(0, 26)` to loop over `my_list` and get 5 items each time.

**I don't know if this is the best approach. So is there any more efficient way to do the stuff?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `itertools` module you can cycle and slice a string via an infinite generator:

```
from itertools import cycle, islice
from string import ascii_lowercase

def gen(x, n):
    c = cycle(x)
    while True:
        yield list(islice(c, n))

G = gen(ascii_lowercase, 5)

print(next(G))  # ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
print(next(G))  # ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
...
print(next(G))  # ['u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y']
print(next(G))  # ['z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: Curious, how does the `while` end? I rarely use `itertools`.

Comment: @pstatix, It never ends, hence it's an infinite generator. `next` calls with `cycle` + `islice` will make you go round and round forever.

Comment: Ah, so `G` just keeps growing and growing and growing? Or does it lazy grow only when `next` is called?

Comment: @pstatix, It doesn't grow at all. Remember a generator yields *one item at a time*. It doesn't store all items in memory. It just spits out a value every `next` call. If you call `list(G)` your computer might crash since you are trying to exhaust an infinite generator.

Comment: Limited use with them, I should use them more...they are forward iterators (in essence) that don't store in memory (fire and forget).

Answer (score 1):

Debatably simpler solution using a list comprehension:

```
def batch_list(ns, batch_size):
    return [ns[i:i+batch_size] for i in range(0, len(ns), batch_size)]

>>> batch_list('abcdefghijk', 3) 
['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jk']
```

This is a simple construction that I find myself writing often when I want to batch some list of tasks to perform.

EDIT: Just realized the OP asked for the construction to cycle around to the beginning to complete the last batch if needed.  This does not do that and will have the last batch truncated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking,

I took some time to understand the objective of your algorithm but if you want to loop and save all of your sublists I think this should work :

```
def slicing_items(slc_len = 5, lst, iterate_num = 25):
# slc_len correspond to the number of slices, lst is the list of sequences
n = len(lst)
k = 1
p = k * slc_len
slicing_list = []
while k < iterate_num:
    current_slice = []
    if p >= n:    
        for i in range (1, p//n):
            current_slice += lst                  #How many times we passed the length of the list
        p = p % n                                 #How many items remaining ?
        current_slice += lst[-(slc_len-p):] 
        current_slice += lst[:p]

    else:
        current_slice = lst[p-slc_len:p]
    k += 1
    p += slc_len
    slicing_list.append(current_slice)

return slicing_list
```

Output :

```
slicing_items(5,my_list,10)

>>> [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'],
['k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o'],
['p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't'],
['u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y'],
['z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
['e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'],
['j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n'],
['o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's']]
```

However if you just want the last slice over your `iterate_num` then your function should fit perfectly (maybe you should use slicing over than rewriting the list in your first boolean statement for rapidity)

Answer (score 0):

Using generator and slicing:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

def gen(x, n):
    start, stop = 0, n
    while True:
        if start < stop:
            yield list(x[start:stop])
        else:
            yield ((list(x[start:])) + (list(x[:stop])))
        start = stop
        stop = (stop + n) % len(x)


G = gen(ascii_lowercase, 5)

print(next(G))  # ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
print(next(G))  # ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
print(next(G))
print(next(G))
print(next(G))  # ['u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y']
print(next(G))  # ['z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
print(next(G))
```

OUTPUT :

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
['k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o']
['p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't']
['u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y']
['z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
['e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a really interesting problem , if you want to "just" solve the problem go for itertools cycle approach , It have already in-built function, But if you want to enjoy the joy of algorithms building, Go with your own solution and try something :

Here i tried with recursion approach, As you said it will keep going so you have to handle recursion by setting your max limit:

```
import math
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(500)

data=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
try:
    def recursive_approch(m, x, n, hold=0, value=0, left=0):
        print(hold)

        max_time = len(m) / n
        max_t = int(math.modf(max_time)[1])
        left = len(m) % n

        if value == max_t:

            if len(x) == left:
                x = x + m[:-len(x)]
                value = 0
                left = 0
        else:

            hold = x[:n]
            value = value + 1
            return recursive_approch(m, x[n:], n, hold=hold, value=value, left=left)
        return recursive_approch(m, x, n, hold=hold, value=value, left=left)


    print(recursive_approch(data, data, 6))
except RecursionError:
    print('maximum recursion')
```

You have to pass the number for slice so if you want to slice 6-6 then:
print(recursive_approch(data, data, 6))
output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
['g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l']
['m', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r']
['s', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x']
['s', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x']
['y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
['e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
['k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p']
['q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v']
['q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v']
['w', 'x', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
['e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
['k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p']
['q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v']
['q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v']
['w', 'x', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
['e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
...................
```

If you want 3-3 then:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
['d', 'e', 'f']
['g', 'h', 'i']
['j', 'k', 'l']
['m', 'n', 'o']
['p', 'q', 'r']
['s', 't', 'u']
['v', 'w', 'x']
['v', 'w', 'x']
['y', 'z', 'a']
['b', 'c', 'd']
['e', 'f', 'g']
['h', 'i', 'j']
['k', 'l', 'm']
['n', 'o', 'p']
['q', 'r', 's']
['t', 'u', 'v']
['t', 'u', 'v']
['w', 'x', 'a']
['b', 'c', 'd']
['e', 'f', 'g']
['h', 'i', 'j']
['k', 'l', 'm']
['n', 'o', 'p']
['q', 'r', 's']
['t', 'u', 'v']
['t', 'u', 'v']
['w', 'x', 'a']
['b', 'c', 'd']
['e', 'f', 'g']
['h', 'i', 'j']
['k', 'l', 'm']
['n', 'o', 'p']
['q', 'r', 's']
['t', 'u', 'v']
['t', 'u', 'v']
['w', 'x', 'a']
['b', 'c', 'd']
['e', 'f', 'g']
['h', 'i', 'j']
['k', 'l', 'm']
['n', 'o', 'p']
['q', 'r', 's']
['t', 'u', 'v']
['t', 'u', 'v']
['w', 'x', 'a']
['b', 'c', 'd']
.......
```

if you pass 12 :

```
0
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l']
['m', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x']
['m', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x']
['y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
['k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v']
['k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v']
['w', 'x', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
['k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v']
['k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v']
['w', 'x', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
['k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v']
['k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v']
['w', 'x', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
['k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v']
['k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v']
['w', 'x', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
['k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v']
['k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v']
....
```